# Why does static field self assignment compile only with explicit static syntax?

Tags: java, static, initialization

Why does this code compile with explicit static field notation on the right hand side, but not without ?

```
public class A
{
    static int a = ++A.a;  // compiles
    //static int a = ++a;  // error - cannot reference a field before it is defined

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because that's how the spec is written. [Sec 8.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3), to be precise. Specifically, this isn't a simple name, so not all of the conditions for a compile-time error are met.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What's the use case IRL for this kind of thing? The Real Programmer's Principle: It was hard to write, it should be hard to read? ;-)

Comment: @AndyTurner Checked your reference, looks correct to me. If you put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Lothar: It’s just a safety net, with other loopholes (like references from a method or another class).  Letting unusual syntax be an escape hatch is a pretty common approach.

Comment: @DavisHerring My question was more, why somebody wants to do a declaration like `static int a = ++A.a;` in actual source rather than why it's allowed by the specification ;-)

Comment: @Lothar - that is a rhetorical question .....

Comment: @Lothar Do you mean, why would it be preferred to the short version? I assume it was a decision by the lang team that having explicit syntax for static members would be less confusing, or reduce errors. In many places, they have made similar choices to sacrifice brevity to reduce errors.

Comment: @jpaugh My question was why somebody would need to declare and define a static variable by using `static int a = ++A.a` instead of `static int a = 1`. It looks for me more like some way of source code obfuscation technique but am happy to learn about actual use cases out there where you solve a problem this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply how the language spec is written. Specifically, [Sec 8.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3) says:

> References to a field are sometimes restricted, even through the field is in scope. The following rules constrain forward references to a field (where the use textually precedes the field declaration) as well as self-reference (where the field is used in its own initializer).
>
> For **a reference by simple name** to a class variable f declared in class
>   or interface C, **it is a compile-time error if**:
>
> - ...

Emphasis mine.

`A.a` is not a simple name, so it's not a compile-time error.

Comment: One thing bothers me. The declaration of the class variable isn't really coming after it's use. It's coming together with it in the same line.

Comment: @user889742 the wording was updated in JLS 9. I've updated here.

Comment: These rules are designed to avoid common use-before-initialization mistakes.  The `<classname>.<staticname>` syntax allows the programmer to say "I know what I am doing" in complicated situations; e.g.  where there are unavoidable cyclic initialization dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Andy's answer I would like to show some examples that are taken from this JLS [chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3). They explains the **Use Before Declaration** rules, demonstrating valid & invalid cases:

```
class UseBeforeDeclaration {
    static {
        int a = UseBeforeDeclaration.b + 2; // ok - 'b' is not accessed via simple name
    }

    {
        c = 1000000; // ok - assignment    
        c = c + 100; // error - right hand side reads before declaration    
        int d = c++; // error - read before declaration    
        int e = this.c * 2; // ok - 'c' is not accessed via simple name
    }

    static int b;    
    int c;
}
```

Also, after the byte code investigation for the valid `static int a = ++A.a` line, we can see that it is get compiled into:

```
static <clinit>()V
  L0
    LINENUMBER 4 L0
    GETSTATIC src/java/A.a : I
    ICONST_1
    IADD
    DUP
    PUTSTATIC src/java/A.a : I
    PUTSTATIC src/java/A.a : I
    RETURN
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
public class A {
    static int a;

    static {
        ++a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: And neither does your edit. You merely updated your answer to repeat the OP's observation. An answer about byte code cannot possibly be an answer to a question about a compilation error. The question is *why* the compilation error.

Comment: @EJP I added multiple interesting examples of code from the JLS that helps to understand the behavior in addition to Andy's answer.